# Trying to find the transformer for my doorbell

Tags: electrical, doorbell

I replaced our doorbell with a Ring doorbell about a month or two ago. It worked fine at first, but gradually started not connecting to the network, and after I followed a few steps suggested by the technician, it doesn't seem to getting any voltage at all. He said it was probably either a chime issue, or the transformer. I tried replacing the chime, but didn't get any change in results, so now I'm trying to find the transformer. Unfortunately, the house was partially wired by the owner, who I can't get ahold of anymore (and yes, I know that generally you don't contact the prior homeowner after purchase), and I'm quite confused. My best guess for the doorbell wire looks like it snakes back to this:

[image: White box attached to junction box (?)]

I haven't been able to budge the screws in it yet to test it with my multimeter (I'm getting 0V at the screws), but does this look like it might be a transformer of some sort?

I've tried testing the voltage at my chime (0 V) and at the wires in the front (0 V), assuming that I was correct in testing the two wires at each of those locations, and I wasn't supposed to bridge two of them to get the reading.

Just to follow up, I was able to get the screws off (and unfortunately lost both in the process), and sticking my multimeter into the holes does yield 18 V. I managed this after getting off the phone with the Ring guy, who'd assured me that this was not a transformer and that I'd need to call an Amazon-recommended electrician...

So now I need to get replacement screws and then see if I can find a break further down the wire.

Comment: Umm, that is a transformer... I've seen transformers mounted in several places... The basement, the attic, as well as in the wall behind or attached to the chime...

Comment: Silly question, do I need any special sort of screw for what the wire attaches to?

Comment: Those look like either #6 or #8 screws. Probably 1/2" in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide an answer for the question, this is outputting the correct voltage and it was identified by a commenter as a valid transformer. I will accept in 48 hours.